# Im trying to add a £ symbol to my calculotor i can't seem to do it

Tags: javascript, currency

```
function fillconcert() {
    concert.options.length = 0;
    var e = document.getElementById("concert");
    var artist = document.getElementById("artist").selectedIndex

    switch (artist) {
        case 1:
            var arr = new Array("210.00");
            fillList(arr, e);
            break;

            case 2:
                var arr = new Array("260.00");
                fillList(arr, e);
                break;

            case 3:
                var arr = new Array("275.00");
                fillList(arr, e);
                break;

            case 4:
                 var arr = new Array("290.00");
                 fillList(arr, e);
                 break;         

            case 5:
                 var arr = new Array("210.00");
                 fillList(arr, e);
                 break;

            case 6:
                var arr = new Array("255.00");
                fillList(arr, e);
                break;
    }
}



function total(number1,number2){
    var amount = document.getElementById("concert").value
    var adding = document.getElementById("cost").value
    var addingTwo = document.getElementById("people").value
    var intOutput = (adding)*(addingTwo)*parseFloat(amount);

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
}
```

this is a dynamic drop down so when they select an option it will give them a price, but when they enter everything it displays just as numbers. is there anyway around this?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking or what the problem is, please edit and add details.  Making the code more readable would also help.

Comment: i have made a form where they select a concert then enter how many people are going i want it so when it displays the price it has the £ symbol at the start of it

Comment: @JamieHunter They meant to edit your main post with that information :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should add it at the beginning of the HTML :

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "£" + intOutput;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for the total but not for the drop down select bit

Comment: and we are supposed to know what that select bit is??

Comment: where the options are. where it has the prices and case 1 case2 ect

Comment: Be more specific. What is select bit ? What code are you running ? What did you try knowing how to concatenate strings ?

Comment: case 2:

                var arr = new Array("260.00");

                    fillList(arr, e);

                        break;   that is one of the prices it gets displayed in a drop down how would i make that also have a £ symbol on it?

Comment: Well, that depends on *whatever* `fillList()` is/does, which we don't know; again please edit your question and add the relevant code.